# Victory Charts - tooltip on line chart

Tags: reactjs, tooltip, victory-charts

Quick question - I have a line chart based on Victory Charts i'd like to display a tooltip on, when someone hovers over the data.

https://formidable.com/blog/2016/09/19/victory-0-12-0-the-one-true-tooltip/

Indicates a 'VictoryVoronoiTooltip' may be helpful.

However, that doesn't appear to be part of the current Victory charts release. I get a 'not found' message during compilation. Further;

https://formidable.com/open-source/victory/guides/tooltips/

[image]

Here suggests the same... but clicking the 'VictoryVoronoiTooltip' link gets me a 404.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5):

Was looking for the same thing and came across [this example](https://codesandbox.io/embed/vyykx3jp77) . If you remove the `<VictoryLabel />` component, the tooltips appear correctly as you hover over the line. Hope this helps!